# VBA code shows "Type Mismatch" error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA code that throws "type mismatch" error, its the second `if` statement that is throwing the error.I think its the comparison operators that are creating the problem but don't know how to fix it. Some help please

```
  If var1 = "IT" 
    If (var2 = "a") & (var3 >= 30) & (var3 <= 300) & (var4 <= 96) & (var5 <= 1) Then
        MsgBox "Compatible system is machine 1"
    End if
  End If
```

Comment: change `&` to `AND` and also check types of `var3`, `var4` and `var5`

Comment: @simoco Thanks, it was '&' which was creating the problem, silly mistake. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

`&` is for string concatenation.

You are probably looking for the `And` operator to perform boolean operations.

Answer (score 1):

It might the variables might be having the numbers in the form of text and it is comaparing the text with numbers like . Consider Var3 = "30" (Number 30 but is text) and it is comparing "30" > = 30 which is a mismatch.
This is one of the possibility.